# let vs def in clojure

Tags: lisp, clojure, let, function

I want to make a local instance of a Java `Scanner` class in a clojure program.  Why does this not work:

```
; gives me:  count not supported on this type: Symbol 
(let s (new Scanner "a b c"))
```

but it will let me create a global instance like this:

```
(def s (new Scanner "a b c"))
```

I was under the impression that the only difference was scope, but apparently not.  What is the difference between `let` and `def`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The problem is that your use of `let` is wrong.

`let` works like this:

```
(let [identifier (expr)])
```

So your example should be something like this:

```
(let [s (Scanner. "a b c")]
  (exprs))
```

You can only use the lexical bindings made with let within the scope of let (the opening and closing parens). Let just creates a set of lexical bindings. I use def for making a global binding and lets for binding something I want only in the scope of the let as it keeps things clean. They both have their uses.

NOTE: (Class.) is the same as (new Class), it's just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 35):

LET is not "make a lexical binding in the current scope", but "make a new lexical scope with the following bindings".

```
(let [s (foo whatever)]
  ;; s is bound here
  )
;; but not here
```

```
(def s (foo whatever))
;; s is bound here
```

Comment: I see, so kind of like C#'s using or Python's with but without any destruction (which would be kind of dumb given immutable state anyway).

Answer (score 14):

Simplified: **def** is for global constants, **let** is for local variables.

Comment: No, that is an oversimplification, and exactly this lead to the original asker's confusion.  LET creates a _new_block_ with lexical bindings, whereas DEF only makes a new "global" binding.

Comment: Sounds wrong to me. Def always binds to a Var, and thus is not a constant. Namespace bindings can also be changed, so they're even less of a constant. Let is a constant, it can not be changed or re-binded at all. So at the very least I would say: "def is for global variables, let is for local constants.

Answer (score 13):

Correct syntax:

```
(let [s (Scanner. "a b c")] ...)
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for them is different, even if the meanings are related.

let takes a *list of bindings* (name value pairs) followed by expressions to evaluate in the context of those binding.

def just takes one binding, not a list, and adds it to the global context.

Answer (score 4):

You could think of `let` as syntactic sugar for creating a new lexical scope with `fn` then applying it immediately:

```
(let [a 3 b 7] (* a b))  ; 21
; vs.
((fn [a b] (* a b)) 3 7) ; 21
```

So you could implement `let` with a simple macro and `fn`:

```
(defmacro fnlet [bindings & body]
  ((fn [pairs]
    `((fn [~@(map first pairs)] ~@body) ~@(map last pairs)))
   (partition 2 bindings)))

(fnlet [a 3 b 7] (* a b)) ; 21
```