# Clojure list member cast error

Tags: list, function, clojure

I try to write function thats return true if element exist in list and false if not.

My code:

```
(defn is_member [elem ilist]
  ((elem []) false)
  (if (= elem (first (list ilist))) 
    (true)
    (is_member elem (rest (list ilist)))
  )
)
```

I try to run it:

```
(is_member 1 '(1,2,3,4))
```

But get error:

```
#<CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

What's wrong? How can i fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're coming from a language with more extensive pattern-matching than Clojure has; `((elem []) false)` is basically nonsense in Clojure. Instead, just test whether `ilist` is empty.

There are a number of other errors, so here's a snippet that actually works while being as close to what you intended as possible:

```
(defn is_member [elem ilist]
  (cond (empty? ilist) false
        (= elem (first ilist)) true
        :else (is_member elem (rest ilist))))
```

Comment: +1 for good answer, one additional point is that I would suggest using "recur" rather than "is_member" in the last line since the function is tail-recursive and can clearly benefit from this optimisation.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence, because, I don't understand the relevant code with Clojure!