# Strange output in Clojure Web Crawler

Tags: html, clojure

I have the following problem. I'm doing WebCrawler for a school assignment, and I'm doing it in Clojure. Here is the code.

```
(defn crawl [url current-depth max-depth]
(def hrefs (get-links url))
(if (< current-depth max-depth)
    (map crawl hrefs (iterate eval (inc current-depth)) (iterate eval max-depth))
    hrefs))

(defn get-links [page] 
($ (get! page) td "a[href]" (attr "abs:href")))
```

The `get!` and `$` functions is not written by me, I've taken them from here: https://github.com/mfornos/clojure-soup/blob/master/src/jsoup/soup.clj

My problem is that when I call `(crawl "http://bard.bg" 0 0)` from repl I get the following output:

```
("http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=1" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=2" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=4" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=5" "http:/
("http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=1" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=2" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=4" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=5" "http:/
("http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=1" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=2" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=4" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=5" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=6" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=10" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=17" "http://www.bard.bg/genres/?id=24"
...
```

So where do the first `2` lazyseqs are coming from? Why are they *unfinished*?

Seems like the problem is in the Clojure-Soup and more specifically here:

```
(defmacro $ [doc & forms]
   (let [exprs# (map #(if (string? %) `(select ~%)
                  (if (symbol? %) `(select ~(str %))
                     (if (keyword? %) `(select ~(str "#"(name %)))
                        %))) forms)]
 `(->> ~doc ~@exprs#)))`
```

Comment: Please share a link to the library and version you are referring to.

Comment: https://github.com/mfornos/clojure-soup here it is the repo I got it from.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the problem you described. In my case `(crawl "http://bard.bg" 0 0)` returns a list of 174 strings.

However, I'd like to take this opportunity to point you to an incorrect usage of `def` in the `crawl` function. Instead of `def` you should use `let`. Additionally, instead of `(iterate eval ...)` use [`repeat`](http://www.clodoc.org/doc/clojure.core/repeat).

```
(defn crawl [url current-depth max-depth]
  (let [hrefs (get-links url)]
    (if (< current-depth max-depth)
      (map crawl hrefs (repeat (inc current-depth)) (repeat max-depth))
      hrefs)))
```

For discussion see [let vs def in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622785/let-vs-def-in-clojure).

Comment: Yeah, (count (crawl "http://bard.bg" 0 0)) is returning 174 for me too, but the output of the "crawl" has this strange (... (... (".." "..")

Comment: Here it is how it looks like:
http://imageshack.us/f/198/screenshotfrom201301121.png/

Comment: @user1972465, I guess it's a problem with printing in the terminal. Have you tried changing the size of the window? Try again in an unmaximised window. I'll be surprised if it helps but it might work.

Comment: That was my first thought, that its some kind of printing problem, but I decided it's not when I did (def something (crawl...)) and "something" had this bonus too. 
Thanks for the help! : ))