# Exceptions: Unbound cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named,compiling

Tags: exception, clojure

I am trying to use clj-http/client to retrieve a web page. It looks like it is kind of working, but sometimes I receive this kind of Exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Var$Unbound cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named,compiling:(/tmp/form-init8570082100332402765.clj:1:72)

This is a simple function which retrieves an url from a database (from jdbc/query :row-fn), requests the contents of the url and writes it to the database. The proxy data is random and just for reference.

```
(defn get-source
  "get content of an url"
  [row]
  (def my-proxy "72.159.148.20")
  (def my-port 10000)
  (def my-url (:url row))
  (def h {"User-Agent" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"})
  (try
  (def my-body (:body (client/get my-url {:proxy-host my-proxy :proxy-port my-port :follow-redirects false :headers h  :conn-timeout 100000})))
  (catch clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo e
    (prn "caught" e))
    )
  (write-data-to-db my-url my-body))
```

The value of row is coming from simple db query:

```
(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (def db-spec
    {
 :subprotocol "mysql"
 :subname "//localhost:3306/a"
 :user "user"
 :password "pass"})
 ((jdbc/query db-spec ["SELECT url FROM main where html is null and url is not null limit 2"] :row-fn get-source)))
```

Thanks for healthy criticism,  I have fixed my example to be more correct.

```
    (defn get-source
      "get list of urls to grab in"
      [row]
      (let [proxy "107.161.31.220" port 8080 url (:url row) 
h {"User-Agent" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"}]
      (:status (client/get url {:proxy-host proxy :proxy-port port :follow-redirects false :headers h  :conn-timeout 100000}))))
```

I hope this way it much better, and I can not get that Exception any more, so could be it was buried inside that mess I came with initially.

Comment: It's hard do read code without indentation. PS: learn about `let`

Comment: I used `def` where I could use `let`, where else I could help with indentation? On my screen it looks pretty intended, almost as good as in clj-http examples.

Comment: what is the data-structure and value of row?

Comment: I just added to main post, so its like `{:url "http://something"}`

Comment: "I used def where I could use let" are you aware that `def` only creates mutable global containers? This isn't like def in Scheme. Your code will do unpredictable and wrong things if you ever use threads.

Comment: no really I am not aware, I already read [let vs def](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622785/let-vs-def-in-clojure) and I will fix it. as I said in the topic title, I am new, I would say new in programming, besides some very simple tasks in perl..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not idiomatic in Clojure (or it's just not declarative) to def something inside a function or "block". Def declares global variables.

From http://clojure.org/special_forms:

> (def symbol init?)
>
> Creates and interns or locates a global var with the name of symbol and a namespace of the value of the current namespace. <...> def yields the var itself (not its value).

I guess you have to put (write-data-to-db) inside try-block and use let instead of def. Right now you're trying to access value of something that might fail.